# connect asp.net to mysql on linux error of connection

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, database, windows

i can't hosting to connect to mysql database on linux  i have this error message : 
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

i need your help thx; this is my code

[image]

Comment: I have added your image, but the next time it is better to copy/paste the code as text instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this message came from an exception thrown by your `con.Open()` call.  The message means your attempt to `Open()` the connection failed because Connector/Net (the .net driver for mySQL) couldn't find the server you asked for.  (Never mind the pluralization in "any of the specified MySQL hosts" ; that is for a [loadbalancing / failover feature](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_replication_load) you're probably not using.)

If it took a few seconds for `con.Open()` to throw the exception, that means there was a timeout. That means the host at x.x.x.x did not respond at all, probably because it's not there or behind a firewall.  If you're trying to connect from your home or office to a MySQL server at a hosting service, you may need to go into the [hosting service's control panel and whitelist](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/308) your own machine's IP address.

If `Open()` threw its exception quickly, it means the host is there, but it is not running a MySQL server.

Pro tip: Always wrap your `Open()` calls in their own `try{}catch(){}` clauses;  failed database connection attempts are not an unexpected occurrence. [Here is an explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-errors.html).